# remove numbers from an Array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class ChessMethod {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      String line=" 1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 g6  0-1]";
      String[] elements = line.split("[\\s.]+");
      String first = elements[1];
      String[] trailing = Arrays.copyOfRange(elements,1,elements.length);

      System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(trailing));

  }
}
```

Output= [1, d4, Nf6, 2, c4, g6, 0-1]]

I would like to get rid of the "1.","2." part of the move list and only keep the

d4, Nf6... I was going to add them to a list.

Is there a better way to do this with a delimiter?
Do I have to make a method that checks the (if there is one)  numerical value of every String in my Array, and saves the ones that dont have one?

Comment: Use `"\\s*\\d+\\.\\s*"` as delimiter, then split on whitespace?

Comment: This is a great help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String line=" 1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 g6  0-1]";
        String[] elements = line.split("[\\s.]+");
        List<String> sts  = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String st : elements) {
            if(st.matches(".*[a-z].*"))
                sts.add(st);
        }
        System.out.println(sts);
```

This ouputs

```
[d4, Nf6, c4, g6]
```

May be this is what you want, if I am not missing anything

Comment: This is what I was looking for! at the if statement, is that regex or a delimiter? What is the difference between them. Thanks!

Comment: st.matches(".*[a-z].*") checks if the string contains any char between a-z. If you want the add capital char also .. you can just change it to [a-zA-Z]

Comment: thats regex.... that just searching for any char between a-z like I mentioned in prev comment. Let me know if you have any other question. Mark the answer correct please if this helped. Thank you !